# Is a Value changed through Input?

Tags: wpf

How do I know when is a value of any control changed by user input (interaction with mouse or keyboard)?

Any suggestions? Is there a common way for this?

EDIT:

I am seeking for attached property or extending already given controls or whatever is needed just to get notified whether user input is taking place at the time value is changed. eg ComboBox SelectedItem changed by user input (User could enter text or select an item in drop down menu)

Its pure View thing therefore I am sorry but no ViewModel solutions for this issue will be accepted.

Comment: Can you provide more precision? Where do you want to add the reactive code? What kind of behavior do you want to introduce? In theory, you don't have to handle such logic in the control itself.

Comment: I did take a look at edits

Comment: Are you planning to write a WPF User Control for this?  or a Custom Control?  Or are you asking about controls in general?

Comment: I plan on having an attached property or extending any control by events or whatever is needed just to get notified that user is inputing something. I dont know why is the question downvoted. Whats wrong with it? Whoever downvoted this please dont run away, elaborate why did you do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would simply be to register to the `Binding.TargetUpdated` event, which is fired when the UI-side is updated (while `Binding.SourceUpdated` is fired when the ViewModel-side is updated)

Comment: I guess I cannot use that. a Binding might not always exist. You can use a TextBox without Binding the Text property.

Comment: Well, you need to differ between "value changed from ViewModel" and "value changed from User Input", thus I simply assumed that you View is linked to your ViewModel via bindings. Why would you need to otherwise?

Comment: It should be a common solution used in other projects by other people later. A value can be set from code behind without binding and its not user input. I need to somehow find out if the application is in user input mode. Dispatcher has a priority called input maybe i can get somehow to ask dispatcher if application thread is in input mode. I dont know how to do that.

Comment: I am not happy with this answer but I ll accept it for now

Answer (score 0):

Use a property with backing field in your view model. Introduce a second setter - a `SetProp()` method - that you use inside your ViewModel. That way you can add different behavior, depending on the origin of the call.

```

```
    private bool mMyProp;
    public bool MyProp
    {
        get { return mMyProp; }
        set
        {
            if (mMyProp != value)
            {
                mMyProp = value;
                // Todo: add here code specific for calls coming from the UI
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyProp);
            }
        }
    }

    public void SetPropFromViewModel(bool value)
    {
        if (mMyProp != value)
        {
            mMyProp = value;
            // Todo: add here code specific for calls coming from ViewModel
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyProp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? Could you elaborate

Comment: User interaction occurs directly on the setter of the property `MyProp` via the Binding defined in the XAML file.

Comment: You are suggestion me that the ViewModel should know when is in user input mode but that is not what I wish to achieve. I need the control to know when is one of its values being set by user. The control should know about input, the viewmodel should in my case stay dumb :)

Comment: Actually MVVM suggests to completely model the "state" of the UI by the ViewModel. The UI shouldn't have multiple states for one ViewModel-state. What you are trying to do, is to introduce multiple UI-states for a single ViewModel state, or introduce information into the UI, that is not present in the ViewModel. You may bind additional UI-properties to the ViewModel and solve the issue in the ViewModel.

Comment: Focus, Input, and all those things are pure UI. They have nothing lost in ViewModel.